# How to remove the fade out delay in windows 7's aero peek?

Tags: windows-7, windows-registry, aero

I am trying to remove or tweak the delay time in aero peek fading out. I am not referring to the time it takes before aero peek shows up after hovering over the task bar, instead i am talking about the amount of delay that occurs after you move your mouse away from the aero peek and before the preview disappears.

Comment: Do you wish to increase or decrease the delay?, mine is pretty fast when moving away.

Comment: Decrease the delay

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There doesn't seem to be a way to adjust this, short of just disabling peek altogether.

Answer (score 1):

Use regedit to browse to `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Advanced` and create a new DWORD value DesktopLivePreviewHoverTime with base decimal and the delay value in milliseconds.

via [askvg.com](http://www.askvg.com/how-to-adjust-aero-peek-desktop-preview-delay-time-in-windows-7/)

Update: Crap, I misread your question and answered the very question you weren't asking.  I'm not aware of a way to change the timeout for the Aero peek view to go away.